# RenderHint and ASP .Net Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

A while back, when ASP .Net Dynamic Data was fresh into beta, we had built a test site with it, checking out its functionality.  It was kind of left there not the subject of much attention.

I've now gone back to the site to make modifications, lo and behold, when i tried to load the site, i got this error:

> The type or namespace name 'RenderHint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think RenderHint is UIHint?

You also need these NameSpaces included:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

The name was changed after the beta.  You should be able to fix it with a find & replace.

Answer (score 0):

Gang! 
In further searching on this, i found the readme for the .Net 3.5 sp1, that together with Robert Harvey's response, does good things for me!
http://www.asp.net/downloads/3.5-sp1/Readme/#_Attributes

Comment: THis was helpful on using UIHint as well:
http://blogs.telerik.com/atanaskorchev/posts/08-04-16/radcontrols_and_asp_net_dynamic_data_-_part_deux.aspx